# Word 2007 Equations: How to stack symbols

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, latex, equations

Does Word 2007's equation editor have any equivalent to the `\stackrel` or `\overset` commands in LaTeX?

I'd like to be able to stack custom text on top of `=` signs, etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `\above` and `\below`:

```
a=\above("foo") b
```

becomes

```
a=┴"foo"  b
```

which becomes

[image]

A more or less complete description of the formula language in Word is given in [Unicode Technical Note #28](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf), although the final implementation differs somewhat in some areas. Unfortunately this is the only real documentation that's there (I asked the author of the math typesetting stuff at MS :-)).

Comment: +1. (I would give you +10 if I could!) Thank you very much! I have been under the impression that this *cannot* be done in Word at all!

Answer (score 0):

See this article : [Superimposing Characters](http://sbarnhill.mvps.org/WordFAQs/CombineCharacters.htm).

The basic idea is to insert a field of type equation containing `EQ \o (x,y)` where x and y are the characters you want to superimpose.

Comment: Nice, and it even works inside equations. But see here: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pan/documents/latex/stackrel.html ... `\stackrel` does an entirely different thing than *superimposing* characters on top of each other. It merely stacks them.