# Seeking a means to add "right harpoon upward" above a variable in equation editor in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

Edit: I specifically stated in my question that using \above is not an acceptable solution because of line-spacing issues. Nevertheless, this question has twice been marked as a potential duplicate of another Equation Editor accent-mark question where the solution was using \above.

This edit is simply to indicate in the body of the question that this is *not* a duplicate and that I needed specific, alternative solutions. I have since discovered a list of all Math AutoCorrect options in Word and have identified \rhvec as the solution. As such, I posted an answer to my own question but I can't accept it until after 48 hours. In the meantime, it would be nice to take the duplicate question tag off this question since it is not, in fact, a duplicate. I attempted to indicate this in comments in response to both assertions that it is a duplicate but the tag got applied nevertheless.

---

I preface this question by acknowledging that there is a similar question about adding an arrow by using v\vec which works well. However, I need to add a rightwards harpoon above a letter.

I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 I should note.

I have found that I can use v\above(\rightharpoonup) and that will put a rightwards harpoon up above my v, but it's got a big gap between the v and the harpoon. I want it to be a nice, small gap identical to when I use the gallery selection to go under "accents" and select "rightwards harpoon above".

I would also like to be able to add other accents, so a general reference would be very useful. For example, I'm curious to know where the person who answered the previous question got the \vec from. If there's a table of all such commands somewhere, I'd very much like to know about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word 2007 Equations: How to stack symbols](https://superuser.com/questions/58686/word-2007-equations-how-to-stack-symbols)

Comment: "If there's a table of all such commands somewhere" the best reference I have found is http://www.iun.edu/~mathiho/useful/Equation%20Editor%20Shortcut%20Commands.pdf

Comment: *NOT* a duplicate of what HackSlash has linked to twice now. That uses \above. I specifically stated in the question that \above is *NOT* what I'm looking for because it improperly formats with a large gap between the variable/number and the accent mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging and found that if you go under AutoCorrect Options, there is a tab there for "Math AutoCorrect". There you can see a list of all the \ shorthand commands. One of them is \rhvec which is short for "rightward harpoon vector". This adds the rightward harpoon as a vector symbol over a variable or a number.

So there you have it: a list of all commands AND the way to add this specific accent mark.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of:
[Word 2007 Equations: How to stack symbols](https://superuser.com/questions/58686/word-2007-equations-how-to-stack-symbols)

The answer found there points to this reference:
http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf

I believe you are talking about two things:

1. Inserting Unicode characters
2. Word equations

Edit: Please be more specific with your title. The original Title doesn't make any sense at all because it lacks context.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Your link uses \above. I stated in the question that \above is not an acceptable solution because of the large gap that it inserts. I have since located a solution which I posted as an answer to my own question which I hope will be left up for posterity.